# QR Code using Jquery

Tags: jquery, qr-code

I am having a form on which i have displayed QR Code, And using printThis.js to print the form. QR code was previously displayed and printed easily using google URL but i found that it has been depreciated, Then i googled to find other source and found jquery libraries jquery.qrcode.js and qrcode.js, But now i am facing a problem when i am printing the form QR code is not displaying on it, Probably its displaying QR code as canvas, Here is my code

HTML

```
<img id="test"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#test').qrcode({width: 120,height: 120, text: "Sample QR"});
        printthis();
})
```

How i can make it printable, And secondly let me know if it will work for all browsers are not? And do we have any other solution like google url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-qrcode-0.14.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="qrcode"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        // render method: 'canvas', 'image' or 'div'
        render: 'canvas',

        // version range somewhere in 1 .. 40
        minVersion: 1,
        maxVersion: 40,

        // error correction level: 'L', 'M', 'Q' or 'H'
        ecLevel: 'L',

        // offset in pixel if drawn onto existing canvas
        left: 0,
        top: 0,

        // size in pixel
        size: 200,

        // code color or image element
        fill: '#000',

        // background color or image element, null for transparent background
        background: null,

        // content
        text: 'no text',

        // corner radius relative to module width: 0.0 .. 0.5
        radius: 0,

        // quiet zone in modules
        quiet: 0,

        // modes
        // 0: normal
        // 1: label strip
        // 2: label box
        // 3: image strip
        // 4: image box
        mode: 0,

        mSize: 0.1,
        mPosX: 0.5,
        mPosY: 0.5,

        label: 'no label',
        fontname: 'sans',
        fontcolor: '#000',

        image: null
    }
    $('#qrcode').qrcode(options);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But it will not print the Q R code, Check the question

Comment: @Ricky It is strange. I have everything working well. Show your code is fully

Comment: I am sorry to say that, I copied your whole code and created a new file, Its not even displaying QR, Am i making mistake in giving options? Here is how i am giving options 
$('#qrcode').qrcode({text: "Sample QR"});

Comment: @Ricky Are you using https://larsjung.de/jquery-qrcode/ ? Are you sure you include this library? The fact that I have your example works well

Comment: @Ricky I will record video for you.

Comment: Thanks Alot Dear, It Worked, My Fault, was copying incorrect file of jquery, Thx alot once again

Comment: @Ricky am glad it helped! make sure to select the answer which was the most helpful to you as future readers will also find it useful

Answer (score 0):

https://larsjung.de/jquery-qrcode/

> The available options and their default values are:
>
> // render method: 'canvas', 'image' or 'div'
>
> ```
> render: 'canvas',
> ```

Comment: I changed the render method to Image but its not working :-( and Chrome version 51 is not even displaying Q R using the same code